# Reading alternating binary data into Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, binaryfiles

I have a data file that's in a binary double data format as far as I can tell goes like this:

[column1value1][column2value1][column1value2][column2value2]...etc

I have been able to look at the [fread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) documentation and figure out how to extract column1's data by using skip.  A double is 8 bytes long and I therefore assigned a skip value of 8. Here is my code:

```
fID = fopen('141518-10000-2.bin');
skip = 8;
A= fread(fID,'double',skip);
fclose(fID);
```

This returns me column 1 of the data into A. How do I offset this by one data point now to get column 2's data?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the second column the same way, you can use [`fseek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) to go to the first value in column 2 and then continue with `fread` the same way you are doing:

```
fseek(fID,8,'bof');
```